# Is that restful API's path correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I just want to make sure is it ok. Basically, I want to create middleware that will handle a request about leaving a group by a user. Is that correct:

> /users/:id/groups/:id

Comment: yes  correct in node js

Comment: It's completely up to you. If you want, your API path could be `/never-gonna/:id/give-you-up/:id`

Comment: I think better will be you have a group and in the group  you have user.

/group/:id/user/:id

Comment: It's a rickroll comment

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, it's for sure better. I have basically two paths that one and yours and both are created in my database so I have to do an update in the group's collection and the user's collection.

Comment: @bhavesh, its not correct in nodejs, it depends on the library you are using to parse this path. Node doesn't know or care what this is. It's just a string and nothing more for it.

Comment: @TheFool yes, for express route it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that is correct. Really depends on the way your are styling your routes. Both User and Groups would have to be updated